# How to set indeterminateDuration programmatically in android?

Tags: android

Is there a way to change the android:indeterminateDuration in runtime to my custom progressbar?

This is how i do it with xml:

```
<style parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar" name="customProgressBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/mp3</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">60000</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no related method in the reference, so I think you can't do it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:indeterminateDuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this ->

[How to make progressBar indeterminate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29)

You just need to use it like this->

```
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Comment: I have already made it indeterminate. I just want to be able to set 'indeterminateDuration' from my activity and not from an xml file.